# How do you connect country and state combo boxes in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The following produces country and state combo boxes, which work beautifully but are not connected (i.e. if you choose "Canada" as the country, the state combo box still lists U.S. states instead of Canadian provinces). Does WooCommerce provide a simple way of connecting these?

```
<? woocommerce_form_field("shipping_country", array("type" => "country")) ?>
<? woocommerce_form_field("shipping_state", array("type" => "state")) ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I just figured it out. These fields **must be siblings** in order for this functionality to work (i.e. they must have the same parent element in the DOM).

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, adding the following code to any Wordpress template will give you a working set of country and state select boxes:

```
<?php
woocommerce_form_field("billing_country", array("type" => "country"));
woocommerce_form_field("billing_state", array("type" => "state"));
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-country-select' );
?>
```

Or the following code if you also want to use WooCommerce's built-in Select2 plugin:

```
<?php
woocommerce_form_field("billing_country", array("type" => "country"));
woocommerce_form_field("billing_state", array("type" => "state"));
wp_enqueue_script( 'selectWoo' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'select2' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-country-select' );
?>
```

You also need the WooCommerce plugin installed and activated of course.